# Find all functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies $f(x)-y+f(f(y))=f(x+y)+f(f(x))$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-equations

> Find all functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies $f(x)-y+f(f(y))=f(x+y)+f(f(x))$.

**My Attempt**

\begin{align}
&P(x, x): f(x)-x+f(f(x))=f(2x)+f(f(x)). \\
&\Rightarrow f(2x)=f(x)-x. \\
\ \\
&P(x, y): f(x)-y+f(f(y))=f(x+y)+f(f(x)). \\
&P(y, x): f(y)-x+f(f(x))=f(x+y)+f(f(y)). \\
&\therefore f(x)+f(y)-x-y+f(f(x))+f(f(y))=2f(x+y)+f(f(x))+f(f(y)). \\
&\therefore f(2x)+f(2y)=2f(x+y). \\
&x=\frac {a+b}{2}, y=\frac{a-b}{2} \Rightarrow f(a+b)+f(a-b)=2f(a)
\end{align}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no such functions.

Set $y=0$.  Then $$\require{cancel}\cancel{f(x)}+f(f(0))=\cancel{f(x)}+f(f(x))$$  So $f^2$ is constant.  Now set $x=0$.  Then $$f(0)-y+\cancel{f(f(y))}=f(y)+\cancel{f(f(0))}$$  (The canceled terms are equal because $f^2$ is constant.)

But then $$f(f(y))=f(f(0)-y)=\cancel{f(0)}-\cancel{f(0)}+y$$ which is not constant.

Answer (score 2):

I think you've almost done everything.

Since $P(a,b):f(a+b)+f(a-b)=2f(a)$, then $P(x,x):f(2x)+f(0)=2f(x)$.

And we know $f(2x)=f(x)-x$, so $2f(x)=f(2x)+f(0)=f(x)+f(0)-x$.

$f(x)=f(0)-x$. I'll let $f(0)=c$, then $f(x)=c-x$ form.

Let's put this back into the first given condition.

$f(x)-y+f(f(y))=(c-x)-y+y=c-x$, and $f(x+y)+f(f(x))=c-(x+y)+x=c-y$.

This makes contradiction, so there are no such function.